# Re-importing TKINTER

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, import, toplevel

I have a file that uses a TKINTER GUI, then imports another script which should open a Toplevel. The new script doesn't identify the Toplevel though unless I also add "from tkinter import *" to it as well. I'm wondering why I have to re-import tkinter for this purpose?

main script:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # initialize tkinter
root.geometry('307x730')


def decode():
    if cust_active or def_active:
        print("Currently Obtaining Data - Stop Data Recording to Decode Files")
        return
    import decoder
    return


decode_button=Button(root, text="Decode Data", command=decode).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

decoder.py:

```
decode = Toplevel()
```

Comment: That's how Python works. Everything that's not built-in has to be imported on a per-module base. And that's a good thing. What if your decoder.py had its own ``Toplevel()`` method, that now does not get used and instead it would use the one from tkinter, just because some other module did ``from tkinter import *``?

Comment: Right on - that's a good point I hadn't thought of. Thanks! Just wanted to make sure I wasn't implementing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Both modules need to have tkinter imported otherwise the tkinter classes won't be available to your second module. Each module have to have their own imports.